# NSRunLoop and NSAutoreleasePool, how do they interact?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool, nsrunloop

> autorelease pool will be released at the end of the run loop.

Does that mean the end of any iteration of loop? 
When does this happen?

> After every touch, motion, or remote control event is processed, the
>   pool will be drained.

What if our application does not provide any touches?

If we use code like this, how can we be sure that the object is not freed between 
`[self someObject]` and `retain` in `someMethod`?

```
- (id) someObject
{
    return [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (void) someMethod
{
    SomeClass * object = [[self someObject] retain];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-c autorelease a variable up a chain of methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878875/obj-c-autorelease-a-variable-up-a-chain-of-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in terms of the call stack.

In the example you give above, `-someMethod` doesn't exit before the value returned from -`someObject` is retained and assigned to `object`.